# HtmlAgilityPack - how to get attribute value covered in single quote?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="search_posts">
<article class="xxx"  data-id='79642521778' data-type='photoset' <!-- many other attributes in single quotes-->> Article text 1 </article>
<article class="xxx"  data-id='84701653287' data-type='photoset' <!-- many other attributes in single quotes-->> Article text 2 </article>
</div>
```

I need to get the id of the 1st article, i.e. 79642521778.

What I done so far:

```
//assuming that the HtmlDocument has already loaded
string test = doc.GetElementbyId("search_posts").SelectNodes("//article").First().OuterHtml;
test = doc.DocumentNode.GetAttributeValue("data-id", "NULL");
```

And it returns NULL. How I can get the proper value? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, that HtmlAgilityPack is still the best tool. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065031/is-the-html-agility-pack-still-the-best-net-html-parser . Consider https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the `data-id` attribute on your `doc.DocumentNode`, not your `article` node.

```
var articles = doc.GetElementbyId("search_posts").SelectNodes("//article");
var firstDataId = articles.First().GetAttributeValue("data-id", "NULL");
```

Comment: oh, I forgot to add 1 extra line of code in my snippet. But I've rewritten it according to your answer. Thanks.